# Luajit FFI directly dereferencing semantics for values not requiring conversion

Tags: c, lua, luajit

What is going on in the code below when I dereference a pointer to a double?

My reasoning is that as it is first class type with a 1:1 correspondence to the c-type it should be able to work with the values directly after a deference, especially when pointers are crossing the execution context, and not values.

So, when I read from the value will Lua create a temporary double, copy into it, and then print it? or will it just directly use the underlying double?

Similarly for writing is Lua able to generate assembly for directly writing into the double?

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static double x;

void set_double(double in)
{
    x = in;
}

double * get_double()
{
    return &x;
}

void print_double()
{
  printf("%f\n",x);
}
```

lua code

```
ffi.cdef [[
  double * get_double();
  void print_double();
  void set_double(double in);
]]

local lib = ffi.load('test');

--lib.set_double(10)
--lib.print_double()
local d = lib.get_double()
d[0] = 20               -- directly writing to * double without any conversion,or redundant copies?
lib.print_double()
print(d[0])             -- directly reading from double without any conversion,or redundant copies?
```

Answer (score 1):

When data is passed between the two language boundaries it undergoes a conversion according to the rules listed on [**this table**](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_semantics.html#convert_tolua).

When you deref a `double *` and read its value over here:

```
  print(d[0])
```

After the deference, the value is converted from a `double` into a lua_Number and then passed back into Lua space. That converted value is what gets passed into `print` afterwards.

For a write access like here:

```
  d[0] = 20
```

The lua_Number '20' gets converted to a `double` first when it crosses the C boundary and then subsequently stored into the location `d` points to.

So can you know if any extra copying is happening under the hood? By inspecting the source of course! The functions of interest for handling the conversion:

```
// lj_cdata.c:242
/* Convert TValue and set C data value. */
void lj_cdata_set(CTState *cts, CType *d, uint8_t *dp, TValue *o, CTInfo qual)

// lj_cdata.c:208
/* Get C data value and convert to TValue. */
int lj_cdata_get(CTState *cts, CType *s, TValue *o, uint8_t *sp)
```

A `TValue` is apparently how luajit internally refers to lua values and objects. When the value of a `cdata` is queried from a lua script (eg. when you do `print(d[0])`), `lj_cdata_get` is called. `lj_cdata_set` is used to handle writing lua values into a cdata (eg. `d[0] = 20`).

What is basically happening is that the lua_Number value on the virtual stack is `memcpy`ed into the memory location pointed to by `d`. In this case, that would be `static double x;` from your C module.

The only extra copying done is getting that lua_Number on and off the virtual stack. The conversion functions themselves works directly on that stack value by accessing `lua_State`'s internal fields.

The other functions of interest are in lj_cconv.c:

```
// handles CType = TValue
lj_cconv_ct_tv
// handles TValue = CType
lj_cconv_tv_ct
// CType = CType
lj_cconv_ct_ct
```

Comment: This explanation is correct. But I think the main takeaway point is: LuaJIT doesn't box doubles, so there's no need to create temporary objects. And since the FFI follows C semantics, it does **not** work on references when accessing scalars inside FFI structs or arrays.